# Doxygen for Protobuf files or similar tool with little modification to comment format?

Tags: text-processing

I have been given a challenge for my first week at work as a graduate and I am stumped already, The company I work for uses google protobuf files - Grpc and I know extremely little about protobuf - Grpc.

**My tasks is:**
*We are using doxygen to generate HTML documentation from source code. Want something similar for .proto files*.

This is getting me down, I can not find anything yet that works out the box for a windows PC and works with protobuf files and outputs as HTML.

I have installed Doxygen but it does not support protobuf files is there a plugin or any other work around please?

**Edit:**
I have installed proto2cpp and I have created a config file and edited as the wiki says too, but I am getting an error when trying to run it, something about python?

```
C:\Users\emartin>doxygen
Adding custom extension mapping: .proto will be treated as language c
Searching for include files...
Searching for example files...
Searching for images...
Searching for dot files...
Searching for msc files...
Searching for dia files...
Searching for files to exclude
Searching INPUT for files to process...
Searching for files in directory C:/Users/emartin/Desktop/test_proto_files
Reading and parsing tag files
Parsing files
Preprocessing C:/Users/emartin/Desktop/test_proto_files/test.proto...
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  <------ is this the issue?
operable program or batch file.
Parsing file C:/Users/emartin/Desktop/test_proto_files/test.proto...
Building group list...
Building directory list...
Building namespace list...
Building file list...
Building class list...
Associating documentation with classes...
Computing nesting relations for classes...
Building example list...
Searching for enumerations...
Searching for documented typedefs...
Searching for members imported via using declarations...
Searching for included using directives...
Searching for documented variables...
Building interface member list...
Building member list...
Searching for friends...
Searching for documented defines...
Computing class inheritance relations...
Computing class usage relations...
Flushing cached template relations that have become invalid...
Computing class relations...
Add enum values to enums...
Searching for member function documentation...
Creating members for template instances...
Building page list...
Search for main page...
Computing page relations...
Determining the scope of groups...
Sorting lists...
Freeing entry tree
Determining which enums are documented
Computing member relations...
Building full member lists recursively...
Adding members to member groups.
Computing member references...
Inheriting documentation...
Generating disk names...
Adding source references...
Adding xrefitems...
Sorting member lists...
Computing dependencies between directories...
Generating citations page...
Counting data structures...
Resolving user defined references...
Finding anchors and sections in the documentation...
Transferring function references...
Combining using relations...
Adding members to index pages...
Generating style sheet...
Generating search indices...
Generating example documentation...
Generating file sources...
Generating file documentation...
Generating page documentation...
Generating group documentation...
Generating class documentation...
Generating namespace index...
Generating graph info page...
Generating directory documentation...
Generating index page...
Generating page index...
Generating module index...
Generating namespace index...
Generating namespace member index...
Generating annotated compound index...
Generating alphabetical compound index...
Generating hierarchical class index...
Generating member index...
Generating file index...
Generating file member index...
Generating example index...
finalizing index lists...
writing tag file...
lookup cache used 0/65536 hits=0 misses=0
finished...
```

Comment: How do the `.proto` files look like? Which version of doxygen are you using. Have you looked at the `EXTENSION_MAPPING`, `FILTER_PATTERNS` configuration settings?

Comment: Hello i am making good progress i have it almost running i am just unsure where to place the proto2cpp.py file??

Comment: Good that you have it almost running, but what have you done. Your comment is vague and it does not show what you have done.

Comment: Sorry i have followed the wiki page and created a config file and the other following steps as seen at https://sourceforge.net/p/proto2cpp/wiki/Home/ I can use the config with cmd and it shows the adjustments however it is not working as intended. I think i need to do something with the proto2cpp.py file as for now it is just sat on my desktop ?? do i need to point the proto2cpp.py to somewhere ? is this correct: INPUT_FILTER = "python C:\Users\emartin\Desktop\proto2cpp.py"

Comment: Just try `doxygen -d extcmd` and see if the command you get looks OK,

Comment: I get the same. i get this error with any cmd, Executing popen(`python C:\Users\emartin\Desktop\proto2cpp.py "C:/Users/emartin/Desktop/test_proto_files/test.proto"`)
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: So what is the python command name on your windows system, is it in the PATH?

Comment: You have lost me, please explain as if i am super stupid, ahhhhhh it seems my work PC does not have python installed, what should i use  and do, just install the lastest python ide ?

Comment: Just install python (when allowed by your company), IDE is not necessary.

Comment: Ok i am installing Python 3.7.3 :) thank you for your time and help, hopefully i have something to show my collages today

Comment: Still the same after installing python 3.7.3 i shall restart my PC to be sure and report back soon. 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Alas still the same after a reboot of the PC, i just read that i may need to add an environment path to python for this PC ? should i do so ?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and i need to add an environment path i assume but because it was installed as an App so the path is not the commonly seen path, does this look correct for the environment path ? C:\Users\emartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

Comment: Best is to add it to the environment path. Shown path looks OK (don't know if there is a bin directory or not). Also check if the python executable is called python.exe and not e.g python3.exe. Instead of using it from the PATH (preferred) it is also possible to specify the complete path with the python command in the INPUT_FILTER.

Comment: What error do you get? Is the proto2cpp.py a python 2 or a python 3 script?

Comment: From wheer did you get the proto2cp.py ?

Comment: I made a mistake and somehow merged the files no doubt a silly cmd i entered, i replaced the proto2cpp file and the python path is added to the environment paths and created the config file and all works now. I am truly thankful for your help as i would not have got this working. Your a star pal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[proto2cpp link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proto2cpp/)

Proto2cpp is a great tool which works with the existing Doxygen tool " my work uses version 1.8.15" with very little setup. You need to have Python installed and make sure python is recognized in CMD on it's own, if you get 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, then you need to add the path to the Python root folder in environment paths, i am using windows 10 so it was in

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
```

but if you are using windows 7 it will be elsewhere just search for the PythonXX folder where XX is the first 2 version numbers with no spaces or points.

Once you have python installed, then follow the proto2cpp wiki steps to make the config file "or download the example in the code tab" and then download the proto2cpp.py file in the code tab within there web page. You can then run a test using the test proto script and cmd using the command

```
doxygen C:\Users\myName\doxyfile    <-- or where ever you have your config file you created i named mine doxyfile.
```

Comment: Please specify the doxygen version you used.

Comment: Have also a look at: https://github.com/4hopp/proto2cpp here are some additional fixes and other proposed patches.

Comment: My work has it already installed and i am not allowed to just update Doxygen but to answer your question i am using Doxygen 1.8.15

Comment: 1.8.15 is currently the latest release,